# Spring boot considers log4j2.xml as logback config file

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I have simple spring boot application:

**log4j2.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Extra logging related to initialization of Log4j.
 Set to debug or trace if log4j initialization is failing. -->
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Appenders>
        <!-- Console appender configuration -->
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <!-- Root logger referring to console appender -->
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6</version>
</parent>
 ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    ...
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j-slf4j-impl.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-layout-template-json</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When I start the application I see the following error:

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'classpath:log4j2.xml'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@3:17 - no applicable action for [Properties], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Properties]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@4:42 - no applicable action for [Property], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Properties][Property]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@14:50 - no applicable action for [Property], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Properties][Property]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@22:56 - no applicable action for [Property], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Properties][Property]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@23:44 - no applicable action for [Property], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Properties][Property]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@24:49 - no applicable action for [Property], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Properties][Property]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@25:46 - no applicable action for [Property], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Properties][Property]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@26:50 - no applicable action for [Property], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Properties][Property]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@27:43 - no applicable action for [Property], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Properties][Property]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@28:34 - no applicable action for [Property], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Properties][Property]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@29:34 - no applicable action for [Property], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Properties][Property]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@30:34 - no applicable action for [Property], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Properties][Property]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@31:38 - no applicable action for [Property], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Properties][Property]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@32:39 - no applicable action for [Property], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Properties][Property]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@34:16 - no applicable action for [Appenders], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@35:52 - no applicable action for [Console], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][Console]]
...
```

Looks like spring-boot try to parse `log4j2` configuration like logback config file.

How can I fix it ?

### Update 1

In effective pom I see following logback related sections:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.11</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.11</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.11</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
      <version>7.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-logback</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.13</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
        <artifactId>simpleclient_logback</artifactId>
        <version>0.15.0</version>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
      <version>7.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

related `ch.qos.logback` depdendency:tree result:

```
[INFO] +- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:3.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO] |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.11:compile
```

### Update 2:

I've corrected depdency like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

But I still see the initial error but depdendency:tree doesn't return any logback-classic

### Update 3:

After project update in intellij I see another error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unable to create Lookup for ctx
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ServiceLoaderUtil
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThreadContextDataInjector.getServiceProviders(ThreadContextDataInjector.java:77)
```

Comment: check your effective pom/dependency resolution/target folder: how comes `ch.qos.logback.*` there?

Comment: @xerx593 Please read topic update

Comment: exclude `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic` from `org.liquibase:liquibase-core`!? ;) (analogous to "starter-web"-"starter-logging" ;)

Comment: @xerx593 I still see the same error but there no `logback-classic` on result of `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: @xerx593 oh my bad - please read Update 3:

Comment: then, (of course...update3) is my bad! :) ...

Comment: 1. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-liquibase/index.html

Comment: Do you mean to add ?
``` 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-liquibase</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @xerx593 unfortunately adding depdency didn't help

Comment: Your "Update 3" indicates that the version of `log4j-core` you are using is newer than the version of `log4j-api`. Spring Boot starters use the `log4j2.version` to manage Log4j2 dependencies. Just set the property to `2.19.0` in your POM and remove the explicit versions.

Comment: It seems to come down to the question: "how to spring-boot, liquibase with log4j?" ...

Comment: but one last "gutshot": please revert the logback exclusion and try: rename file to `log4j2-spring.xml` (hoping to sneak around the original problem)